python3 version gone wrong
For many reasons I've installed many variant of python3. And all of the sudden switching it by sudo update-alternatives --config python3 doesn't work for me now. Somehow it's showing python 3.12.4, which I've never recognized installing before. What's worse is that it seems to f up my ros from time to time. Is there anyway to fix or just remove all python3 except 3.8.
brianlee@brianlee-ROG-Zephyrus-M16-GU603HM-GU603HM:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.11   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    1         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.8 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in manual mode
brianlee@brianlee-ROG-Zephyrus-M16-GU603HM-GU603HM:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.12.4
brianlee@brianlee-ROG-Zephyrus-M16-GU603HM-GU603HM:~$ roscore
... logging to /home/brianlee/.ros/log/9418859c-7011-11ef-8768-e3d499745670/roslaunch-brianlee-ROG-Zephyrus-M16-GU603HM-GU603HM-31906.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://brianlee-ROG-Zephyrus-M16-GU603HM-GU603HM:38501/
ros_comm version 1.16.0


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 347, in main
    p.start()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 316, in start
    self.runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 676, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 651, in _setup
    launched = self._launch_master()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 413, in _launch_master
    validate_master_launch(m, self.is_core, self.is_rostest)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 83, in validate_master_launch
    if not rosgraph.network.is_local_address(m.get_host()):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 170, in is_local_address
    local_addresses = ['localhost'] + get_local_addresses()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 212, in get_local_addresses
    import netifaces
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netifaces'


As far as I know, you should not be messing with the default python3 with update-alternatives. If you want multiple versions installed, that's fine. But you need to keep your default python3 pointed to version 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04. If you want to use a different version of python like 3.6 for example, you will need to call the command python3.6 instead of calling python3. This is because many system components run on python3 and they expect to be calling python3.8 when python3 is called. At this point, I would update alternative and choose version 3.8.

I'm not showing a python3.11 available on 20.04 so is it possible you installed through a ppa? Does version 3.11 or 3.12 show when you run dpkg -l | grep "python3\.11\|python3\.12"

@mchid yeah that's the problem, choosing 3.8 lead to the 3.12 result I showed in the code above. I'm kinda a noob and been switching using update-alternatives cause that's the first thing it showed when searching for swapping python versions, and it does work at least for a while.

I updated (edited) that last comment. Also, what does file /usr/bin/python3.8 show?

@mchid it's all 3.11 whe nrun 'dpkg -l | grep "python3.11|python3.12"', yet the version displayed 12.

@mchid 'file /usr/bin/python3.8'  showed '/usr/bin/python3.8: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=7d4a7d9cde7d2d977b52da0a6c84bb2ee25b4217, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
'

Okay, then run which python3 to see where it is pointing. /usr/bin/python3 might be later in the path than another one like /usr/local/bin/python3 so this might be the issue.

wait a second,' /home/brianlee/anaconda3/bin/python3 ', I'm not even in my conda

Is /home/brianlee/anaconda3/bin/ early in your path, before /usr/bin when you run echo $PATH?

I believed that's earlier, /opt/ros/noetic/bin:/home/brianlee/anaconda3/condabin:/home/brianlee/anaconda3/bin:/home/brianlee/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

As a suggestion, you should consider using Anaconda to switch between Python versions and leave the system one alone (i.e., just have one installed).  Many other programs depend on it and you might end up creating problems for yourself later.

I'm not familiar with conda but I was thinking that if scripts call for /usr/bin/python3 (and I'm not sure if that's what all system scripts use in the shebang), then this might not be a problem?

But if it's messing up ros then I guess that's a problem. Do you know how you set the PATH to include the conda path? Was this set in profile or bashrc or someplace? I think you can grep for this: grep PATH ~/{.profile,.bashrc}

Do you know how you set the PATH to include the conda path? -- Conda installer will do it for you
